# django - markdown tags become html in edit form

Tags: django, markdown

i added markdown filter on my index page like ;

```
{% load markup %}
{{ post.body | markdown }}
```

it works correctly when i saved post with markdown tags. but if i want to edit it ; it doesn't look like :

```
**bold text**
```

it looks like :

```
<strong>bold text</strong>
```

in my edit form. how can i fix this?
 as i know ; markdown must save the text as markdown codes into db.

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need the [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#std%3atemplatefilter-safe) filter

```
{{ post.body | markdown|safe }}
```

Comment: should i use this filter in index page or form?

Comment: it doesnt work. still same. i have markdown filters only in index.html. not loaded into form.html page. should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Using safe filter so that it won't escape

```
{{ post.body | markdown |safe }}
```